# Dynamically drop down menu generation in AngularJS + Spring MVC

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am totally new in angularJS, I want to implement Dynamically drop down menu generation with updating the arrayList of vacancies,  in AngularJS with spring MVC. I also want to update the arrayList of vacanciesaccordingly.
I have populated the dropdown values from $scope.dropdown values.

Two things to do: 
First populating the data for vacancies available from Json request.
Second by pressing the [+] button, new vacancy(Occupation) section should be populated, and finally changes should be effected in the arrayList of vacancies.

Please give me a head start how to implement this.

I did something like this :

```
<div  ng-repeat="vacancy in vacancies" ng-init="vacancies=${vacancies}">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Occupations</span>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="vacancy.vacancyID" ng-options="aType.id as aType.name for aType in aTypes" ></select>
                        <adda></adda>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Video-Url:</span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vacancy.video" name="twitter"  />
                    </div>  
                    <br />

                </div>
```

Thanks

Json request:

```
{
  "companyID": 50,
  "companyName": "Agrident GmbH",
  "companyUnternehmensprofil": null,
  "vacancies": [
    {
      "vacancyID": 1,
      "beginn": null,
      "number": "3",
      "profile": "Profile text",
      "tasks": "Task test 1",
      "title": "Title1",
      "typeOfApplication": "Angewandte Informatik",
      "typeOfVacancy": "DualesStudium"
    },
    {
      "vacancyID": 2,
      "beginn": null,
      "number": "5",
      "profile": "Profile text",
      "tasks": "Task1",
      "title": "Title2",
      "typeOfApplication": "Elektroanlagenmonteur/-in",
      "typeOfVacancy": "Ausbildungsplatz"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Sample UI]

Comment: Serialize the collection of occupations into JSON and feed that to Angular.  That's a hint.

Comment: @Makoto question updated.